# Ionic ng-model, ng-if, ng-blur not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, binding

I have this code in my html file and all the values from the ng-repeat are correct and shown the way I want. I have some angular directives such as ng-if, ng-blur and ng-model, but none of them are working. I don't have a clue of what can it be.

```
<div ng-if="view===true">
  <div class="serie_list">
      <div ng-repeat="serie in series | filter: { id:id_serie }"
          collection-item-width="'100%'"
          collection-item-height="100">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col col-33">
            <img class="img_item" imagenie="{{url}}/exercicios/{{serie.id_exercicio}}-0.gif" width="100%" height="100%"/>
          </div>
          <span class="col col-67">
            <h3>{{serie.descricao_ex}}</h3>
            <p><span ng-if="serie.tipo_repeticao">{{serie.tipo_repeticao}}: </span><span ng-if="serie.num_repeticao">{{serie.num_repeticao}}</span></p>
            <p ng-if="serie.intervalo"><span>Intervalo: </span><span>{{serie.intervalo}}s</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="info_icon" ng-click="timer()"><i class="ion-ios-timer-outline"></i></span></p>
            <p>Carga: <input type="text" ng-model="serie.carga" ng-blur="salvar(serie.id_exercicio_serie,serie.carga)"/></p>
            <p ng-if="serie.nota"><span>Nota: </span><span>{{serie.nota}}</span></p>
          </span> 
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: try adding dynamically from controller and compile the angular code before appending.

Comment: I am sorry, but how can I do that?